# ViewPager2 disable transition animation

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have ViewPager2 connected with TabLayout. Other posts referring to ViewPager offer to override setCurrentItem(position, false) where false disables the smooth scroll. However, TabLayoutMediator calls onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) which calls viewpager.setCurrentItem(postion, true). How can I override this behavior if TabLayoutMediator is final, as well as ViewPager2?

Have already tried:

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
        }
    });
```

And overriding onTabSelected like this:

```
     tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getPosition(), false);
        }
         ......
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. The animation lags when changing between tabs with many views and I find it strange that there is no clear way to disable it (do they assume everyone only use 2-3 tabs?). I have looked into the previous ViewPager, but it seems like FragmentPageAdapter which it uses is deprecated on API 27+.

Answer (score 5):

This was added in the release `1.2.0-alpha05` of material, more precisely in this PR: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/951.

If you import the above-mentioned version like in:

`implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05"`

you can disable the animation effect:

```
TabLayoutMediator(tab_layout, view_pager, false, false) { tab, position ->
  ...
}.attach()
```

The last two arguments for the `TabLayoutMediator` are for `autoRefresh` and `smoothScroll`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Weird... I think the line you pointed out in github comment is about selecting the initial position only, later the boolean should be taken into account. Do you have a reproducible sample in github by any chance?

Comment: it was a weird problem, and got fixed by changing the UI. i really didn't know what was making it wrong. i have removed the issue link, to not address  others wrongly.